# check active and inactive session in Oracle NoSQL Database

Tags: nosql, oracle-nosql

How to check active and inactive session through your database command line in Oracle NoSQL as we used to do in the case of oracle RDBMS thru Views...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle NoSQL Database - NoSQL is stateless at the server-side, and we do not have the ability to do that. JE stats can be used to get general activity, that can help.